# Upload de imagens no formulario

Tags: imagem, upload, laravel-5

tenho um form que precisa de upload de duas imagens no mesmo form e que devem ser postadas em pastas diferentes, alguem tem alguma dica ?? Obrigado

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seu form? E o que tentou até agora?

Answer (score 0):

Simples como a morte, você vai precisar de dois campos do tipo `$_FILE`, ex:

```html
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2" />
```

No seu controlador, você vai tratar cada um, ex:

```
$file1 = Request::file('file1');
$file2 = Request::file('file2');

if ($file1)
{
  $file1->move($diretorio, $file1);
}

if ($file2)
{
  $file2->move($diretorio, $file2);
}
```

Pelo que entendi é isso.